# Python Compare the last two non-null values in dataframe column

Tags: python, dataframe, compare

I have a dataframe with columns that are a string of blanks (null/nan set to 0) with sporadic number values.

I am tying to compare the last two non-zero values in a data frame column.

Something like :

```
df['Column_c'] = df[column_a'].last_non_zero_value > df[column_a'].second_to_last_non_zero_value
```

[This is what the columns look like in excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTTEo.png)

[image]

Comment: In your dataframe, are the empty cells 0's or nans?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could drop all the rows with missing data using pd.df.dropna() and then access the last row in the dataframe index and have it return the values as an array which should be easy to find the last two elements in.